# pushlet vs long polling as a push technology

Tags: node.js, push, long-polling

Reading about push technologies/mechanisms
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

what is the difference between

**Pushlet** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Pushlet)

and

**LongPolling** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

Answer (score 1):

Taking citations from the same wiki page :

> "Pushlet - the server takes advantage of persistent HTTP connections"

That is, idea of using a single TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses. So, if a request is sent from the client, the server side uses the same connection to send data multiple times (*of course, till the time the TCP connection is open*). The Keep-Alive time is configurable in various servers and can be tuned.

> "Long-polling - If the server has no new information for the client
>   when the poll is received, instead of sending an empty response, the
>   server holds the request open and waits for response information to
>   become available. Once it does have new information, the server
>   immediately sends an HTTP/S response to the client, completing the
>   open HTTP/S Request"

That is, the response is never committed to the client, till the time the server has some information to be shared / returned. Refer below URL to have a working sample in Node.JS :

https://dzone.com/articles/diving-nodejs-%E2%80%93-long-polling

Comment: The link is dead.